# What is the mechanism of calculations on the tuple containing an array?

Tags: indexing, tuples, dolphindb

Take the following example in [Tuple (ANY Vector)](https://docs.dolphindb.cn/en/Programming/DataTypesandStructures/DataForms/Vector/TupleANYVector.html#ariaid-title5) as an example:

`a=(2, [3, 5], 10); max a; // output [10,10]`
Why `max a` returns [10, 10]? Is it because the vector [3,5] is expanded, thus forming two tuples, [2,3,10] and [2,5,10]? What is the distribution of the related memory?

My current conjecture is that the memory is expanded and the elements are duplicated, either during element storage or dynamic calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If all elements of tuple a are scalars, `max a` compares them one by one; if a contains an array, `max a` iterates over the array to find the maximum, such as 10 in your example. To facilitate subsequent vectorized calculations, the result is converted to a vector with the same length as the longest array in the tuple, resulting in [10,10].